# Perl - illegal hexadecimal digit warning error

Tags: regex, macos, perl, warnings

I'm getting a warning on this line of code:

```
$mismatch = ($_ =~ s/[^\x0]//g);
```

Illegal hexadecimal digit ']' ignored at xxxxxx.pl line 61.
The regex looks valid to me, what is causing this error please?
It's the right square bracket that it doesn't like.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you need `s/[^\x00]//g`

Answer (score 8):

According to the [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#The-Basics),

> Similarly, `\xnn`, where `nn` are hexadecimal digits, matches the character whose native ordinal is `nn`. Again, **not using exactly two digits is a recipe for disaster**, but you can use `\x{...}` to specify any number of hex digits.

So, you need to use

```perl
s/[^\x00]//g
```

Or, `s/[^\x{0}]//g`.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, totally makes sense, I have fixed the error.